# Smart DOM Insertion (preserve styles of child element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

*This is a very odd question, of which I am fairly confident I already know the answer, however, before I go ahead with the fix that I am trying to avoid, I thought it was worth asking others as you may see this from a different angle*

I am currently writing a plugin that takes a certain element (can be any DOM node), and wraps it with a `div`. The purpose of the plugin is to add a 'blinds' effect to elements which can then be used to reveal the element on scroll.

**Note:** *Wrapping with a `div` is absolutely essential to the functionality I am implementing.*

My question, quite simply, is anybody aware of a ***smart*** way to preserve the styles from the element being wrapped and ensure it visually remains the same as it was before the `div` wrapping, **and**, whilst retaining the dimensions so another `div` can be inserted within the wrapper and be the same dimensions of it's sibling.

See this very basic example (before and after - **notice the blue blind**):

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.test:nth-child(1) {
  background: #999;
}

.test:nth-child(2) {
  background: #666;
}

.test > * {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.test h1 {
  margin: auto 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.test p {
  margin: 0 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
}

.test-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: max-content; /* Fix for example purposes */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Fix for example purposes */
}

.test-wrapper .blind {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h1>Before wrapper inserted</h1>
  <p>Some description</p>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <div class="test-wrapper">
    <div class="blind"></div>
    <h1>After wrapper inserted</h1>
  </div>
  <p>Some description</p>
</div>
```

Before answering, these are the solutions I am trying to avoid:

- 'copying' or 'moving' the styles (or certain styles) from the child to the parent as this is likely to cause a huge mess... Open to suggestions though
- Defining styles for `test-wrapper` in the site's CSS as `test-wrapper` is a plugin specific element.

The obvious, and very easy, solution is to just define the styles for the wrapper instead of the child in my CSS (SCSS). I appreciate this may be the only way, but I ideally want to avoid this as what I am building is a plugin and I want the HTML/CSS to work with and without the element wrapper in place.

Comment: probably using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55407828/8620333

Comment: or align the content using flexbox rather than margin `justify-content:center`

Comment: I had absolutely no idea `display: contents` even existed!! That is amazing, thank you! In regards to the `justify-content`, the example I posted, was literally just an example. I am referring to all styles, not just margin, or alignment if that makes sense?

Comment: *I am referring to all styles, not just margin* : we can never cover all the cases. It will depend on your specific code and your specific design.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - of course, I wasn't expecting to cover all cases, it was more than I was hoping to cover as many as possible...

Comment: @TemaniAfif - from my initial tests, it seems that `display: contents` is a perfect solution! For any cases where this doesn't work, I can just define the styles manually for the wrapper element outside of the plugin. If you want to post up an answer, I will happily accept it, otherwise I will delete the question.

Comment: I will then close as duplicate since the situation is almost the same. No need to delete your question, it can bring search results.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I have just noticed an issue actually that you may be able to assist me with... It seems that `display: contents` removes the element from the flow of the DOM in which case, it won't actually solve my issue as I need a child element of the wrapper to have width and height of 100% of the wrapper (i.e. the same size of the sibling). Is this possible?

Comment: this is the behavior of display:contents --> *display: contents causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself. This can be useful when a wrapper element should be ignored when using CSS grid or similar layout techniques.*

Comment: @TemaniAfif - damn it, in that case it isn't suitable as I need the wrapper to take the width and height of the contents so I can place another element within it with 100% width and height :-(

Comment: so you need to add more context and a real use case not a simplified example. as I said, we cannot have generic solutions. We need to know your requirement to give you a precise answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I will update the question now

Comment: @TemaniAfif - See updated question

Comment: not sure if I can help more on this but it sounds to me an X/Y problem. Probably your *wrapping* idea to have *blinds* is the issue. Well, more people will come and help ;)